# Use Define and Constant in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I've a question about the #define in Inno Setup. I've make a setup who's working well and i'm thinking of the future of app if i have some modification to do. For example, if i change the version (Major, Minor, Build, Patch,...) i doesn't want to change all the line (like Registry) at each time.

So i try to make something like that :

```
#define MyAppMajor "5"
#define MyAppMinor "5"
#define MyAppBuild "1"
#define MyAppPatch "1"

...

[Files]    
Source: "D:\ProgramFiles\..."; DestDir: "{app}\Program\{MyAppMajor}.{MyAppMinor}\"; Flags: ignoreversion;

[Registry]
Root: "HKLM32"; Subkey: "Software\program\"; ... ; ValueData: "{MyAppMajor}.{MyAppMinor}.{MyAppBuild}.{MyAppPatch}";
```

But that doesn't compile and it says :

*"Unknown constant "MyAppMajor".Use two consecutive "{" characters if you are trying to embed a single "{" and not a constant"*.

Is there a way to do something like that for versionning or another constant ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed to use the `#` char (or [`#emit`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit), which is the longer version of the same), that is used to inline a defined variable into the script, e.g.:

```
#define MyAppMajor "5"
#define MyAppMinor "5"
#define MyAppBuild "1"
#define MyAppPatch "1"

[Files]
...; DestDir: "{app}\Program\{#MyAppMajor}.{#MyAppMinor}\"; Flags: ignoreversion;

[Registry]
...; ValueData: "{#MyAppMajor}.{#MyAppMinor}.{#MyAppBuild}.{#MyAppPatch}";
```

When missing this, the compiler expected (built-in) constants called `MyAppMajor`, `MyAppMinor` etc., whose doesn't exist; hence the error.

But, what you're trying to replicate is probably built-in in Inno Setup as the [`AppVersion`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appversion) directive. It might be useful e.g. in conjunction of reading the version of the application binary from its included file version information:

```
#define AppVersion GetFileVersion('C:\MyApp.exe')

[Setup]
...
AppVersion={#AppVersion}
```

Comment: Hello, that's working fine for [Files] and [registry] but if i want to do something like that : `#define MyAppVersion "{#MyAppMajor}.{#MyAppMinor}.{#MyAppBuild}.{#MyAppPatch}"` that doesn't work. Can i make something like that ?

Comment: Yes, just remember, that `{#...}` stands for `#emit` and that you cannot use emitting when defining variables. You need to use variables as such, so use `#define MyAppVersion MyAppMajor + "." + MyAppMinor + "." + MyAppBuild + "." + MyAppPatch` instead.

Comment: P.S. writing `#expr SaveToFile("C:\PreprocessedScript.iss")` to the very end of the script can help you with *debugging* preprocessor tasks since it saves the preprocessed script to a given file where you can see the script just as it's given to the compiler.

Comment: Working very well. Many Thanks TLama

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't found something in Inno's documentation explicitly stating it, there is an example where the `+` operator is used to concatenate strings. I think you can get by with something like this:

```
Source: "D:\ProgramFiles\..."; DestDir: "{app}\Program\" + MyAppMajor + "." + MyAppMinor + "\"; Flags: ignoreversion;
```

If that doesn't work, there is a `StringChange` preprocessor macro that should work but will be uglier, especially in strings with multiple substitutions:

```
#define MyAppMajor "5"
#define MyAppMinor "5"

#define InstallDirectory StringChange(StringChange("{app}\Program\%major%.%minor%", "%major", MyAppMajor), "%minor%", MyAppMinor)

Source: "D:\ProgramFiles\..."; DestDir: InstallDirectory; Flags: ignoreversion;
```